# Customer Indicator Label in Backtesting.py

Tags: python, back-testing

I am learning backtesting.py and try to do a strategy with custom indicators of RSI and ADX based on pandas_ta library. When I call for the ta.adx() function in the backtesting's self.I() function, I got 3 data series because that's the data from the ta.adx() function.
I can get the data with no issue and they get assigned to 3 series ( [self.adx, self.dmp, self.dmn] ) properly. However, when I plot it using bt.plot(), all 3 series are being labeled as "adx(14)" instead of "adx(14)", "dmp(14)" and "dmp(14)". I have searched through the document and there is a "Name" argument in the self.I() function but it only allows one name override. There seems to be even fewer options in bt.plot() function too regarding to custom labelling.

Wonder if there is anyway to hack this labelling limitation.

Also, what if I only need adx and not all 3, is there anyway to plot ONLY the ADX?

here are my codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import yfinance as yf
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy

class RSIxADI(Strategy):
    rsi_win = 2
    adx_win = 14

    def init(self):
        self.rsi = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_win)
        [self.adx, self.dmp, self.dmn] = self.I(ta.adx, pd.Series(self.data.High),pd.Series(self.data.Low),pd.Series(self.data.Close),self.adx_win)

    def next(self):
        #print(len(self.adx), self.adx[-1:], self.dmp[-1:], self.dmn[-1:])
        pass
        
df = yf.download("SPY", period="1Y", progress=False)
bt = Backtest(df, RSIxADI, cash=10000, commission = 0.002, exclusive_orders=True)
output = bt.run()
print(output)
bt.plot()
```